# C++ qsort issues

Tags: c++

I wrote the following to try to use the qsort() function.  My goal is to input several lines of text and print an alphabetical listing of each word.  This code crashes every time I run it and i am not sure as to why or how to fix it. I also need to add something to count the number of times a word occurs and print that as well but I an mot too sure how to do that.  Any advice would be very helpful.  Thanks!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct to_lower 
{
  int operator() ( int ch )
  {
    return tolower ( ch );
  }
};

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{ 
  //return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
  return (strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b));
}

int main()
{
  string list[900];
  int nLength;
  int i=0, q=0;
  string nTemp; 
  int word[900];

  cout
      << "Enter some lines of text  "
      << "(Enter Ctrl-Z on a line by itself to exit)\n"
      << endl;

  while ( !cin.eof() )
  {
    cin >> list[i];

    transform(list[i].begin(), list[i].end(), list[i].begin(), to_lower());
    word[q]=1;  

    if (list[i]==list[i-1])
    {
      word[q]=+1;
    }
    i++;
  }

  nLength = i;

  cout << "The sorted words would be:\n";

  qsort(list, nLength, sizeof list[0],&compare);

  int n;
  for (n = 0; n < nLength; n++) 
  {
    cout <<" \n"<< n << list[n]<< word[n];  
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When i=0, you are trying to access `list[i-1]` and that gives a negative index. Probable reason for crash.

Comment: This is C pretending to be C++. If you really want to write C++, use `std::vector` instead, and write your own `std::less` or `operator<` implementation, which will enable you to use `std::sort`.

Comment: Please spend some minutes to double-check the indention of your code before posting it. It needs to be fixed: you can edit your question to do this, by clicking "edit" below the post.

Comment: You should change your `while` to `while (cin >> list[i])` to handle the end of file operation correctly.  Search StackOverflow for "end of file" for answers.

Comment: Your program will not operate as designed if the user enters more than one word per line.

Comment: You need to verify that the `i` variable is still within the range of the array, at the bottom of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is not a `char*` as your qsort compare function pretends. Also, you should never use qsort with C++ objects. qsort does not know about objects and won't call copy constructors and may damage the internal structure.

When i=0, using list[i-1] is a bug.

You need to count your duplicate words *after* sorting or you have no guarantee that duplicates are next to each other.

Comment: Also, even if the comparison function were fixed to use string instead of char*, qsort still wouldn't work because it's not a "trivial" type, because it has a user-defined copy constructor, etc.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter What makes you say that?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: qsort swaps elements using a bit-by-bit copy routine, like memcpy.  That only works for trivial types.  Non-trivial types, like `std::string`, need to be copied using their copy constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Technically true but in practice bit-swap will work. Not that I'm recommending it.

Comment: @ZanLynx in practice, a bit-wise swap of non-POD types is undefined behaviour, and should be avoided. It *might* work, but you're programming by coincidence, then.  Which is something that should also be avoided.

Comment: @NathanErnst: Just to defend this idea, if you examine the std::string header files and determine the implementation, you can see if qsort is safe to use or not.